# Android - trying to send POST request, throws an exception with no message

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

Simple code:

```
 String URL = "http://www.google.com";
                        try {
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xocircle.freeiz.com/index.php?id=425231&data=joiragiiij99newooo");
                            // Add your data
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));
                            // execute HTTP post request
                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Log.w("Error", ex.getMessage());
                        }
```

I run it on my android app and it crashes the app.
Here's the message:

```
04-15 18:21:27.645  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/Error﹕ Try to send
04-15 18:21:27.765  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)

04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1227)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:677)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at com.nimrod.xocircle.PlayBoard$1.onClick(PlayBoard.java:94)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-15 18:21:27.770  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-15 18:21:27.775  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 18:21:27.775  16150-16150/com.nimrod.xocircle W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fcdc08)
```

but I can't understand me.

I do have permissions and I do have internet connection.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you have a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException , You need to perform all network operations inside a thread. So just wrap your code within a thread or an Async task and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

        }
    }).start();
```

and put your code inside the `run` method.